# Accessing SDFC page with oAuth token

Tags: ios, oauth, salesforce

I am working iOS app which is using Salesforce oAuth for login.

I would like to load one VF page url in web-container which requires the login to access. As I am already having valid oAuth token, How can I access VF page (salesforce) by passing access token on header request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using framework of `SalesForce iOS SDK` and you have a valid OauthToken :
`SFOauthCordinator` class has a method called `[coordinator authenticateWithCredentials:[[SFAccountManager sharedInstanceForAccount:@"user"]credentials]]`.  This source line gives you a login session by using the existing oAuthToken.

Comment: Bharath, Thanks for your reply. We are not using SalesForce SDK in our application.